# Ultra lightweight and open source email client

Tags: windows, open-source, email

I am looking for a really fast email client.

What I expect should be similar to Sumatra PDF, foobar2000 or MPC-HC. All of these are really amazing, they are super quick and have a clean interface.

Could you recommend me an **open source** email application for **Windows** which is similar? **Portable** at best.

Comment: For Microsoft Windows? /// Do you have tested any portable email clients yet?

Comment: Yes, for Windows. In the past I always used the Gmail website to check my emails but I would like to switch to a real application so I can manage multiple accounts at the same time. If not portable it should be at least ultra lightweight.

Comment: Why not use Thunderbird?

Comment: I used this a few years ago and it seemed too overloaded for me. Way too many functions I will never need. Interface isn't as clear as the applications I mentioned in the question. Look how perfectly clean Sumatra looks like: http://i.imgur.com/BfoYnc5.jpg just features you really need. Same with foobar here: http://i.imgur.com/cehEvPc.jpg and both are really really fast.

Comment: I gave it a chance and it is better as expected but still not perfect. It just doesn't feel as native as the other apps do. For example when I resize the window I feel how it stutters and isn't able to resize smooth

Comment: Imap or pop? Do you need HTML emails to be opened as html?

Comment: Do you want it to be freeware?  You mentioned open source, but since open source <> freeware, I thought it would be best to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

i would suggest [Claws Mail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claws_Mail), a fork of Sylpheed.

but maybe also [Sylpheed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylpheed) (with less features) fit your needs better, because [here](http://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=1112) i found instructions for portable use.

Sylpheed is a lightweight and cross-platform email client

- It runs on Windows
- Clean but featureful interface
- Open source (GPL/LGPL license)
- Portable version available (just [download](http://sylpheed.sraoss.jp/en/download.html) the zip archive, extract, and run). A older PortableApps version is also available [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/darksabre76apps/files/Sylpheed%20Portable%20%28PortableApps.com%29/).

Comment: I was typing a similar answer when I saw yours, so I just edited mine into this one. I hope you don't mind :)